# How to use Firebase with Ionic1 with new SDK?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I am a beginner to Ionic 1 and very new to Firebase. I see the docs in firebase.com are deprecated and we have to use new docs and sdk. Can anyone please give me the tips to start with Ionic 1 with Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, firebase.com has moved to firebase.google.com. Though, you can still work on projects in firebase.com, it is not recommended.

With Ionic 1, you can use Firebase official library, [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire). This has a great documentation as well, to get you started.

Comment: thanks @ankitjain11 Is there any proper tutorials for the new Firebase with Ionic?

Comment: This is a great starting point. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md